# is it quicker to do 24 database queries or 1 database query and sort in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a site accepts entries from users. I want to create a graph that displays the entries over time. Is it more efficient to make 24 calls to the database have sql return the number of entries per hour or should i just do one call and return all the entries and organize them in php?

Comment: Depending on your database schema, one query should definitely be faster, and if you write a proper query you should have minimal "organizing" to do with PHP.

Comment: Can't you try both and just see which one usually takes longer?

Comment: Can you not organise them on the database side too?

Comment: @j08691 yea i think it would be a pretty clean simple foreach loop to group them all.

Comment: Since databases are designed for querying, that is almost certainly going to be faster, but the only way to optimize for your situation is to *try both*.

Comment: seems like i should just test and try

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the data, the database schema and the query.

Usually the less queries you can make, the better.

If it's still slow after optimising the query, cache the result in PHP?

Comment: ahhh you are right, i totally forgot that since this is not a real-time display but archival entries over time i should be able to cache most of it

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your settings, such as database, whether database on the same machine as web server, traffic, ... each call uses some over header on database server, but you do not need sort on web server. I would suggest test it with a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's compare:

1) Query the database for all the values.  Return a large chunk of data across your network to the application server.  Parse all of that data through the client's DBD interface.  Build your own data structures to store the data the way you want it.  Write, document and maintain client code to loop across the detailed data, adding/updating your data structure with each row.

2) Query the database for the data you want in the format you want it.  Let the highly tuned database create the summary buckets.  Return less data across the network.  Parse less data on the app server.  Use the data exactly as it was returned.

There's no "it depends".  Use the database.

Comment: This comment is incorrect.  I have worked with databases where the sort operation wasn't complex, but required some work.  On top of all the other operations the DB had to complete, having it sort the huge amount of data was far too slow.  When I made several small individual queries and then sorted the result we saw a literal 10x or more improvement in speed.  There is DEFINITELY a depends when it comes to where a sort is done.

Comment: Mickey is summing a day's rows and grouping them into hour buckets.  It's not rocket science.

We've all seen lousy databases with missing indexes and bad schemas, but that wasn't his question and I chose not to taint my answer with that kind of baggage.

Comment: That still isn't the only thing to consider. If he has lots of other applications querying the database, or if the data returned is of a certain size, network latency, etc all will greatly impact the performance of his application.  We can't really answer his question usefully without more information about the database (object, Cassandra, etc), how it is used, and the environment of use.